# Apple Notes alternative

Tags: apple, notes

Is there a linux based note taking app that shows an image in the note list like Apple Notes?

The screenshot below is of Apple Notes.  It has a list of recipes in the centre column, with an image for each bullet.

I've tried Joplin, SimpleNotes, StandardNotes and Zim with little success.

[image: Apple Notes]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belong to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree w/ the 'off-topic' designation, but as long as we're here...  Have you considered a Markdown Editor? It's not the same as Apple's Notes, but you can make bulleted & numbered lists and embed pictures. Here's a [list of apps that work on Linux.](https://itsfoss.com/best-markdown-editors-linux/)

Answer (score -1):

What you define as an alternative is rather subjective. I can recommend setting up Nextcloud or renting it out in a cloud. In Nextcloud, you can install Nextcloud Cookbook, an app that can manage your recipes. Furthermore, there exists a simple notes app, to take notes in Markdown or plain text.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Grigorios.  The recipes are just an example. It was the first screenshot I found online.  You mentioned the alternative being subjective.  I am looking for a specific feature (the list image feature that I described in the original post), for which I cannot seem to find it in any linux based notes application.